# Djongo not obtaining Object Array embedded fields correctly with Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, djongo

I am having trouble displaying the codes array as an embedded field      on Django.

- I am connecting Django up to a MongoDB where there are embedded
  documents. (See below) [image: MongoDB]
- Adding the fields in Django Administration works fine. (See below)

  [image: Django_Admin]
- However, on the Django Rest Framework it is not showing it as an
  embedded field.

[image: Django_Rest_Framework]
[image: Frontend]

Here is my code for Django **models.py**

```
from djongo import models
from django import forms


class Order(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, null=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.code, self.quantity)


class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'code', 'quantity'
        )


class Portfolio(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True, max_length=65, default="", blank=False, null=False)
    codes = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Order,
        model_form_class=OrderForm
    )
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research, I found the answer on https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/115.

I altered `serializers.py` to check for EmbeddedModelFields or ArrayModelFields:

The `def get_codes` checks to see if the field is an EmbeddedModelField or ArrayModelField model. If so, then accommodate the field.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from portfolio.models import Portfolio

class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    codes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ('username', 'codes')

    def get_codes(self, obj):
        return_data = None
        if type(obj.codes) == list:
            embedded_list = []
            for item in obj.codes:
                embedded_dict = item.__dict__
                for key in list(embedded_dict.keys()):
                    if key.startswith('_'):
                        embedded_dict.pop(key)
                embedded_list.append(embedded_dict)
            return_data = embedded_list
        else:
            embedded_dict = obj.embedded_field
            for key in list(embedded_dict.keys()):
                if key.startswith('_'):
                    embedded_dict.pop(key)
            return_data = embedded_dict
        return return_data
```

[image: Django_rest_framework]

Answer (score 0):

in version 1.3.1 go to the fields.py file in djongo folder  and copy lines 465 & 466 and add these lines after next if.Done

```
if isinstance(value, dict):
        return value
    
if isinstance(value, ModelSubterfuge):
        value = value.subterfuge

if isinstance(value, dict):
        return value
```